# Angular 5 CLI Server Side Rendering Webpack Issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, server-side-rendering, angular-seo

I followed the wiki from angular-cli wiki for Server Side Rendering in Angular 5.

Followed all the steps properly. I remember it worked last week.
I did not made any changes to my system.

But yesterday when I tried the same steps npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr, I received the below error:

```js
D:\ssr>npm run webpack:server

> ssr@0.0.0 webpack:server D:\ssr
> webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors

 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...s\ts-loader\index.js!D:\ssr\server
Hash: 1008694ea9ba59cc289b
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 917ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server.js  2.85 kB       0  [emitted]  server
   [0] ./server.ts 376 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./server.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterCompile' of undefined

    at successfulTypeScriptInstance (D:\ssr\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\instance
s.js:147:28)
    at Object.getTypeScriptInstance (D:\ssr\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\instance
s.js:48:12)
    at Object.loader (D:\ssr\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:16:41)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! ssr@0.0.0 webpack:server: `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --
progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ssr@0.0.0 webpack:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eshiksha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-08T08_20_
00_651Z-debug.log
```

Would appreciate your help.

Package.json file :

```js
{
  "name": "ssr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: an error image is not visible avoid pasting images as it won't be clear for someone who is trying to helping you.

Comment: MY EYES ARE BLEEDING! 1000% ZOOM DOES NOT SUFFICE.. Please copy paste the error as text.

Comment: Please post error in the code, not as a screenshot which is not of really good quality

Comment: its been half an hour, waiting for you to paste the code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, My Internet went down @shakyl mansuri

Comment: can you show your package.json file ?

Comment: @David updated the package.json code in my question.

Comment: Maybe try setting ts-loader version to 3.5.0?

Comment: @David I believe I am getting that error when I try this command: `npm run webpack:server`

Comment: I believe that too. Did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is caused due to the mismatch of the ts-loader if the webpack version is 3.x please use ts-loader 3.5.0 and this should resolve the issue.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/729

Answer (score 0):

@David Yes my friend you were right it was because of the ts-loader:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9783